# How to import multiple database at once through SSH?

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh

I am attempting to restore my mysql database to my website, and all of the tables in my database get dropped into individual files, so I am trying to figure out how can I restore all of the database .sql files through SSH with a single (or easy command) instead of restoring all 100 tables individually.

Answer (score 11):

```
cat *.sql > data.sql
mysql -u <username> -p < data.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you created the individual files - if they have all the instructions for recreating the tables (i.e., "Drop if exists...", "Create ...", and "Insert into ..."), then you can either concatenate them into mysql:

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u xxx -pxxx dbname
```

or write a script to do it

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -u xxx -pxxx dbname < file001.sql
mysql -u xxx -pxxx dbname < file002.sql
```

The second choice lets you more easily control the order of files processed.

Finally, you might want to create your backups in a more convenient way - check out mysqldump for how to dump a database (or several!) into one file (basically, "mysqldump -u xxx -pxxx dbname > dbname.sql", but there are some helpful flags you might want to add).

Comment: it should be "mysqlDUMP -u xxx -pxxx dbname > dbname.sql" :D

Comment: Yes, indeed; good catch - thank you, @scibuff. I corrected my answer accordingly.